# pod2man not found while installing Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I was trying to install WireShark 1.10.5 in linux.I was following the instructions provided with the software. Now,I am having problems while installing. It says pod2man cannot be found. How can i fix this?

```
checking for pod2man... no
configure: error: I couldn't find pod2man; make sure it's installed and in your path
```

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: I am using fedora 19 @GuyHarris

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [FOSSology bug 5619](http://www.fossology.org/issues/5619):

> the pod2man utility which is used by the build process has been moved to a different package in Fedora 19 called perl-podlators
>
> In previous versions it was in the package perl

so it appears you need to install the package "perl-podlators" to get pod2man.

Answer (score 0):

try

> apt-get install perl-modules

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.